# VBA Use one column from multi column combo box as variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that produces a multi column combo box in a userform showing the Client and ID. I had to produce both columns as the Client and be listed multiple times but the ID is unique.

```
i = 2

For Each c In Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    CB_Account.AddItem Cells(i, 4).Value & " : " & Cells(i, 3).Value
    i = i + 1

Next
```

However I'm using the value selected filter a sheet so that I can copy client details to a new sheet and am using the selected value as a variable:

```
MyAccount = UF_Format.CB_Account.Value
```

The code is currently falling over because the value in the combobox in a concatenation of two columns. Really I need to pull through just the second value being the ID so my code can filter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That depends on what values column 4 and 3 can have. If you can assume that column 3 is always three characters long, then you can user Right, if you know that column 4 contains only letters, you may match a pattern to ignore letters and " : " and take the rest. If there is no easy way, you may want to change the separator, e.g. to a '|'.

Comment: BTW, I would not call this one a multi column combo box, it just has values concatenated from multiple columns of your Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable `MyAccount` as an array, then split the combo box value using colon as the delimiter. You can then work with the second item of the array.

```
Sub second_value()
    Dim MyAccount() As String

    MyAccount = Split(UF_Format.CB_Account.Value, " : ")
    Debug.Print MyAccount(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Except if column 3 or 4 can contain ':'. And I would supply " : " (including spaces) as the second parameter to Split, so you don't need to Trim the result, which may have other effects, as well.

Comment: @z32a7ul True about using " : " as the delimiter, I'll update the answer. I wouldn't expect a name or ID to contain a colon, but of course you would need to take this into consideration :)